# Take plot range literally in R?

Tags: r, plot, limit, subset

I have the following dataset:

```
x = c(4, 5, 10, 30, 50, 51)
y = sqrt(x)
```

And I'd like to plot the data in the x-range from 5-50

```
plot(x,y, xlim=c(5, 50))
abline(v=c(5,50), col="red")
```

But still datapoints from outside of that range are visible.
Is there an easy way to tell the `plot()` to tkae the limit literally.
So far I came up with two ideas:

1. Remove margins of the plot (I actually like the margins, but not the data that become visible)
2. Exclude the data from the variables before plotting them (in my experience that was always tedious - subset() might work when you organize your data in a data.frame)

Comment: Was the below what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

By default R extends the range of the axis slightly (by 4%) before it tries to find *nice* labels breaks (e.g. `2,4,6` or `5,10,15` etc). You can override this with the `par` parameter `xaxs="i"` - standing for `internal`, which you can pass as one of the `...` arguments in your call to plot:

```
plot(x,y, xlim=c(5, 50) , xaxs = "i" )
```

[image]

Some info from the help page for `par` which may be of use:

> ***xaxs***
>   The style of axis interval calculation to be used for the x-axis. Possible values are "r", "i", "e", "s", "d".
>   The styles are generally controlled by the range of data or xlim, if given.
>
> - Style "r" (regular) first extends the data range by 4 percent at each end and then finds an axis with pretty labels that fits within the extended range.
> - Style "i" (internal) just finds an axis with pretty labels that fits within the original data range.

Comment: Damn... beaten by seconds. :-)

Comment: I mean, if i had a penny for everytime that happened to me. I'd be a least a couple o quid better off.